# Segmentation fault (core dumped) gdal with efal Mapinfo

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, mapinfo

I have install efal_19.0 from https://support.precisely.com/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-efal-sdk-download/ this link in order to support nativeX format. after configuring efal in bashrc with efal driver and SDK i am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Steps to Replicate the issue:
1.On ubuntu 20.04 install gdal-bin 3.04 version.
2. Download both SDK and driver from above link.
3. Download driver folder
4./home/user/gdal3_efal_drv
5. Extract EFAL_19 zip file and copy contents of export/common to export uu64
Edit bashrc like this `1.export EFAL_SDK_DIR=/home/user/Downloads/EFAL_19.0/export/uu64 2.export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$EFAL_SDK_DIR 3.export GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=/home/user/efal/drv 4.cp /home/user/gdal3_efal_drv/ogr_EFAL.so $GDAL_DRIVER_PATH 5 source ~/.bashrc`
After editing trying to convert any file using ogr2ogr command. It is showing Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.In the binary folder uu64 of ubuntu. Rename the Ntv2.xml to anything with xml extension.This resolved that issue